# Escape the input box while pressing Shift in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, nautilus, input, shift

This disturbs me for a long time. Pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> may cause the caret to escape the input box. For instance, if I would like to rename the newly-created folder to `underscore _`, it frustrates me. Pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> simultaneously yields weird behavior as below. Hence, copy and paste a single underscore is the only workaround. Besides, the search and replace box in Code::Blocks acts the same as in nautilus; it clears everything I've typed and escape. How to fix this?

[image]